# How to run junit test using java

Tags: java, junit, parameters, concordion

Hello I'm launching a Junit test using java using this code:

```
    JUnitCore junit2 = new JUnitCore();
    Result result2 = junit2.run(thenameoftheclass.class);
```

but in my junit original test there are some "VM option" (the IDEA window of cofig for junit). this VM options have the configuration to loggin in an app, are like the user and password system params. But I am not able to insert those params when I am trying to run junit using just a java program

Comment: Is your project maven based? If not- you will be much better off if you convert it...

Comment: anyway- how are you running the java program? If you use the command line- simply add options: `java -Dkey=value ... my.test.MainClass`

Answer (score 0):

Well guys I was able to find the answer.

First of all you need to know that my project is not maven based.

This methods are cool --->

JUnitCore junit2 = new JUnitCore();
    Result result2 = junit2.run(thenameoftheclass.class);

The problem was that when I was building the Application arguments in Intellij IDE I was filling the app password and user in the field "program arguments" but actually it was meant to be field in "VM Options" becase the java machine uses them in execution time